# How to fix 'Link Highlighting in Inline Code'?

Tags: asciidoc

The method of writing a code element in Asciidoc is by writing an element enclosed in the grave accent(`):

> ```
> `var`
> ```

And, the method to show a link is:

> ```
> link:www.awebistelink.com[var]
> ```

I am attaching an image to show these two on a website that renders Asciidoc
[Image Displaying the output in an asciidoc document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPZYh.png)

When I am trying to show a link highlight of a code element inside an inline code by writing:

> ```
> `link:www.awebistelink.com[var]`
> ```

It renders perfectly fine on Asciidoc [Please see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOYU.png)

But on the website, it doesn't show any link, and simply shows a code element like as if we declared it simply as

> ```
> `var`
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,
it should be

> ```
> `link:www.awebistelink.com[var]`
> ```

I still don't know how it worked but now it works just fine as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to make a link label appear in monospace is to apply the backticks to the label itself, not the link.

Using your example, the markup should be:

```
link:www.awebsitelink.com[`var`]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found the correct way. Please see my answer.

Comment: You found a way, but it's the same way that your question said that it didn't work.